# Can i get the name of the function in javascript in this case ?

Tags: javascript

In the below example i want the function name xyz inside that function.

```
function Abc(){
   }
   Abc.prototype.xyz = function() {
        console.log(arguments.callee.name); //not working
   }
```

Comment: [`arguments.callee` is deprecated](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions/arguments/callee). You can't even use it in strict code now. So no, you can't really get the name of the current function in the general case. Note that here you'd need to name the function anyway: `Abc.prototype.xyz = function xyz() {`

Comment: The function doesn't have a name. The **property name** is *not* the name of the function.